# Query builder where between custom date format

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

My field `date` (`varchar datatype`) is in a custom date format it's `dd-mm-yyyy`.

*Example : `01-01-2016`*

I want to get data between specific dates from a database field `date`.  Let's say input data are stored in variables: `startDate` & `endDate`.

I tried with this query but the result are weird.

```
$query = DB::table('test')->whereBetween('date', array($startDate, $endDate))->get();
```

I think it fails because I used a custom `date` format.

How can this be solved?

---

**@updated**

let's say i have `date` like this

```
29-12-2015
29-12-2015   
29-12-2015
30-12-2015
29-12-2015
01-01-2016
06-01-2016
```

i set `$startDate` & `$endDate` like this

```
$startDate = "01-12-2015";
$endDate   = "01-01-2016";
```

it's even not get any result with this script

```
$query = DB::table('test')->whereBetween('date', array($startDate, $endDate))->get();
```

but if I using

```
$startDate = "01-12-2015";
$endDate   = "31-12-2015";
```

i get all data...which it's wrong result because `2016 data` should not in range...it's somehow like not filtered

Comment: can you post expected results of data?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez in my `update section` i expect to get result between `01-12-2015` & `01-01-2016` which 6 data from top...`06-01-2016` not included because it's not in range

Comment: then what is your problem using whereBetween?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez i don't know why i can't get result like i expecting using range `01-12-2015` & `01-01-2016` i get no result....using range `01-12-2015` & `31-12-2015` i get all data...it's like not filtered

Comment: this is because of your date datatype which is varchar. Try to use build sql query and run it to test.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez yeah u right....i ask this question because if i change my `field` to `date` datatype it's need a lot work to syncronize....maybe there is a way using another script other than `whereBetween`...but i guest it's not possbile

Comment: could you try my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your `date datatype` is varchar you can try to use `str_to_date function` in mysql then before using **`$starDate`** and **`$endDate`** variable convert it's format first.

Sample code is like this.

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("01-12-2015"));
$endDate   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("31-12-2015"));

$query = DB::table('test')->whereBetween("str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')", array($startDate, $endDate))->get();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice it's working now with a few customize to adjust my script :D

Comment: glad it helps.yosh! :)

Answer (score 1):

The format shouldn't be a problem; Unless the data you POST are in different format from what the database holds. Make sure that the format for the `date` field in database matches the format to the ones you store in `$startDate`, `$endDate`.

Also I would solve this by taking a slightly different approach. This can become a model function, call it `getDataBetweenDates()`. Each time you need to query the database, to retrieve the data between a specified range of dates, you do a call to this function from the controller:

- Model

```
public function getDataBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate) {
    $range = [$startDate, $endDate];
    return $this
        ->whereBetween('date', $range)
        ->get();
}
```

- Controller

```
$startDate = Input::get('start_date'); 
$endDate = Input::get('end_date'); 

$model = new Model; // use your model name; 
$data = $model->getDataBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate);
```